# Web Api return DataSet with Get

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, dataset, asp.net-web-api2

I had code in which it works as it returned I assume to proper object type

**jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/News/5',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponses(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });

        //Displays in a Table
        function WriteResponses(allNews) {
            var strResult = "<table><th>Name</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th>";
            $.each(allNews, function (index, news) {
                strResult += "<tr><td>" + news.id + "</td><td> " + news.title + "</td><td>" + news.body + "</td><td>" + news.body + "</td></tr>";
            });
            strResult += "</table>";
            $("#divResult").html(strResult);
        }

    });
```

**Web Api**

```
  public HttpResponseMessage GetNews(int? id)
    {
        int groupValue = 4;

        var tips = (from s in db.tblTips
                  .Where(d => d.@group == groupValue)   
                    select s);

        if (tips == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not found for the Given ID");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tips);
        }
    }
```

**However, That worked above as I was returning IQueryable**

Instead, I have a DataSet that I want to return but it is undefined in the code ( and yes I have changed the names in the variable construction of the table  e.g.   **news.StormOut**  etc..

So this is what I am trying to return, I really do not like working with DataSets and DataTables , so I'm open to changing it....

```
   [Route("GetCheckBox/{id?}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCheckBoxes(int? id)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StormConnString"].ToString()))
        {

            string querystring = "SELECT StormOut, StormYes, StormNo FROM tblSignOnOff WHERE id = " + id;  // 3521 "
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querystring, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "Data");

        }

        //return ds;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've probably moved on for now, but you should't pass .Net objects back from webservices, as it limits the scalability of the calling system.

You should pass back data in a standard data interchange format, such as XML, or JSON. JSON has the advantage in my option when working with a JQuery AJAX call, as the client can use the object as is, and you get a strongly typed object to work with. Using the Newtonsoft JSON helpers from Nuget, its as simple as calling (c#)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
```

Then from your HTML/Javascript side:

```
    var tr = '';
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        tr += '<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td><td>' + item.Age + '</td><td>' + item.Gender + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#HTMLtable').append(tr);
```

Comment: He is passing back XML. The data structure described happens to be a .NET object, but there's nothing stopping him from creating a JS object with the same structure to map it to.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the return type of my .net created Get method to DataTable and received this result. Here's the method:

```
// GET api/values
[AllowAnonymous]
public System.Data.DataTable Get() {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
    dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
    dt.Columns.Add("Col2");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "Column 1 value";
    dr[1] = "Column 2 value";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    return dt;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Test" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Test">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Col1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Col2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
<Test diffgr:id="Test1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Col1>Column 1 value</Col1>
<Col2>Column 2 value</Col2>
</Test>
</DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Comment: I created Web API Core  Get method based on your recommendations to return data table. On client side, I received a string that I was able to convert to XML file.  The string returned by Web API looked  a little bit different. It had "DataTable.RemotingVersion":{"major":2,"minor":0,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"XmlSchema":  header. I could not feed a datatable on client side with this XML file.  I wonder how you did this? Thank you.